# how to catch param conversion error in rescue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning ruby and working on something. I have controller.rb

```
def city
  params.require(:id)
  begin
    @data = @user.city_details(Integer(params[:id]),
                              params[:city_name]
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
end
```

model.rb

```
  def city_details(id, city_name = 'philly')
    StoredProcedure::User::GetCityDetails.exec!(
        id,
        city_name
    )
  end
end
```

How do i update controller to just catch the param id conversion related error and not any model related errors?

Answer (score 0):

I would cast the param before the model method to ensure you are catching the correct thing:

```
id = begin
  Integer(params[:id])
rescue ArgumentError => e
  render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
end
@data = @user.city_details(id)
```

You could also add the rescue at the top level of the controller

```
class MyController

  rescue_from ArgumentError do
    // code here
  end

  def mymethod
    id = Integer(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

just complementing Carl's answer, could be also:

```
id = Integer(params[:id]) rescue render_error(:bad_request, 'Invalid id')
```